# replace part of URL while exporting?

Tags: python, loops, arcpy

I have a list called `shapelist` that has:

```
shapelist

['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pl\\v1\\ASTN\\ASTN.shp',
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pl\\v2\\ASTN\\ASTN.shp']
```

and I want to replace the last part of the directory by maintaining part of the list's contents directory. Example:

in this loop:

```
for i in shapelist:
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i],i.replace('\\ASTN\\ASTN.shp','\\exported\\ASTN_li'))
```

> Gives error: 000210 Description The output cannot be created.
>   Potential reasons include data locking, an incorrect path, and limited
>   access rights.

If I do it like this it works though.

```
arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i],i.replace('ASTN.shp','ASTN_li'))
```

The problem with this is that it saves it to a location that is not wanted.

Do you know how to save it like the first attempt or an alternative way to save it in that specific location?

Answer (score 0):

As I suggest, you should create the folder `'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pl\\v2\\exported'` firstly before doing `arcpy.FeatureToLine_management()`, such as

```
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pl\\v2\\exported'):
    os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pl\\v2\\exported')
for i in shapelist:
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i],i.replace('\\ASTN\\ASTN.shp','\\exported\\ASTN_li'))
```

Comment: Can you write how to work with the loop ?What changed needed?

Comment: try above, do little change

Comment: this can't  possibly work because in every iteration the data comes from different directories.

Comment: you can try 1-loop with shapelist's length 1, in first to make sure whether it can address the problem. If that is the cause, then try to make sure the each different directory exists before you do `arcpy` operation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for every item in the list, since it changes for every iteration, to work for the given case.

```
rootfolder = r'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pl'
for i in shapelist:
...     os.mkdir(rootfolder+'\\'+i.split("\\")[-3]+ '\\'+ 'exported')
...     out = rootfolder + '\\'+i.split("\\")[-3] +'\\'+'exported'+'\\ASTN_li'
...     arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i] ,out)
```